# VS & Resharper Suggestion boxes overlapping in VS

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper, resharper-9.0

When typing in VS, I get 2 suggestion boxes. One from VS, and the other from Resharper and its pretty annoying since VS seems to cover up Resharper.

In the screenshot below, you can see reshaper with 3 suggestions behind VS default suggestion box. Ive reinstalled visual studios, resharper. Ive reset all my settings to default, `Options -> autolist members` disables both of them, i just want to keep the resharper suggestion box. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, this was a bug in the development cycle of ReSharper and Visual Studio 2015 - the GUID used by VS for XAML changed, which meant ReSharper wouldn't recognise and override (hide) Visual Studio's code completion. This was fixed in a later build of ReSharper 9.x (9.0, which you've got tagged, was released before VS2015 RTM). Try and download a newer version of ReSharper. If you only have a license for ReSharper 9, you can get ReSharper 9.2 from the [archives download page](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207242355-Where-can-I-download-an-old-previous-ReSharper-version-).

Comment: 9.2 with 2015 community works as it should. i had 9.0.1 installed. ty